# How to merge four matrices of order 3*3 in to one matrix of order 6*6

Tags: python

I have created two  matrices using Numpy in Python:

```
mat=np.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2]])
mat1= np.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
```

I want to merge these two matrices. How can I do that?
The output should be `[mat,mat1]`

Comment: Your title and your question don't fit. Two or four matrices? Also, the output you propose doesn't look like a `3*6` *or* a `6*3` matrix...

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `(3,6)` matrix, you can use the [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) function:

```
>>> np.hstack((mat, mat1))
matrix([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If you want a `(6,3)` matrix, use [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) instead. `np.hstack` and `np.vstack` are two particular cases of the more generic function [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). Check the documentation for more details.

Finally, if you want a `(2,3,3)` array, just use

```
>>> np.array([mat,mat1])
```

However, because it's a 3D array, you won't be able to view it as a matrix.